# TableViewCell height changes when cell is moved

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, height, row

I am using Autolayout and `estimatedHeightForRowAt`to dynamically change cell height. This is the code I am using:

```
var heightAtIndexPath = NSMutableDictionary()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let height = self.heightAtIndexPath.object(forKey: indexPath)
    if ((height) != nil) {
        return CGFloat(height as! CGFloat)
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let height = cell.frame.size.height
    self.heightAtIndexPath.setObject(height, forKey: indexPath as NSCopying)
}
```

In `viewDidLoad()`

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.reloadData()
```

Now when I do a swipe right to 'complete a task', the `priorityNumber`on which the data is sorted becomes 0 for that particular cell and the cell moves to the bottom of the list. I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` changeType `.move` to move the cell to the bottom automatically when the coreData is changed.

The issue is that the cell changes it's height a bit when moved. It's random - sometimes it changes when it goes to the '0th' position and sometimes it changes when it goes back to it's original position.

It doesn't happen always, but sometimes. Any idea what maybe the issue. Here is the autolayout constraints for the contents in the custom cell:

```
textview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 48).isActive = true
    textview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,  constant: 6).isActive = true
    textview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    textview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scheduledSign.topAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
   // textview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: line.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    _ = scheduledSign.anchor(nil, left: contentView.leftAnchor, bottom: line.topAnchor, right: contentView.rightAnchor, topConstant: 2, leftConstant: 54, bottomConstant: 4, rightConstant: 8, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

    line.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 48).isActive = true
    line.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    line.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
   // line.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textview.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    line.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.5).isActive = true

   _ = prioritycircle.anchor(self.contentView.topAnchor, left: self.contentView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 16, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 8, widthConstant: 20  , heightConstant: 20)
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: You can't return automatic dimension from estimated height. You must return an actual estimate value, even if it is inaccurate. Also, it isn't causing your layout problem but you should use leading anchor, not left anchor for correct behaviour in RTL locales

Comment: I think your problem may also be related to using `indexPath` as the key to your dictionary; when a row moves the height in the dictionary will be the height for the old data at that index path, not the new data.  Really, unless you have hundreds of rows and their height varies widely you should be able to get away with returning a static value for your estimated row height. It is used to calculate the scroll bar offsets.

Comment: @Paulw11 so what do you think i should do? Return a static value or something else?

Comment: Try a static value to start with

Comment: @Paulw11 okay.. will give it a try and let you know

Comment: @OsamaNaeem how did it go?

Comment: Been busy with uni. Will work on the app in the weekends. Will update you guys:)

Comment: @TomHarrington Still having issues!! The cell size changes when it moves.

Comment: @Paulw11 -> the cell still changes height and is really random. Happens usually when the text has 2+ lines: issue is shown in this short video i recorded: https://youtu.be/ecU3_ticw3g

Comment: @Paulw11 Still can't fix this bug. Tried storyboard but having the same issue. Any idea how I can use a different height altogether at newIndexPath's position?